# How to get data for each month from current date sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any help would be great since i'm not good with SQL query :)

Thank you

I have a table called Registration

i would like to get all records of who sign up total from each month.

for example this month is Jun

so the data would bring back

```
January 500

February 200

March 600

April 100

May 800

Jun 400
```

what i have now

```
SELECT count(r.regID) AS totalCount
FROM Registration r with(nolock)
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, createStamp) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate()))
  AND DATEPART(YEAR, createStamp) = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate()))
```

right now its onlu pulling the last month since i dont have any data for Jun

CreatStamp is smalldatetime

Comment: Basically you need to use Group By clause. Go through this link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like all you would need is:

```
SELECT YEAR(CREATESTAMP), MONTH(CREATESTAMP), COUNT(R.REGID) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM REGISTRATION R
GROUP BY YEAR(CREATESTAMP), MONTH(CREATESTAMP)
ORDER BY YEAR(CREATESTAMP), MONTH(CREATESTAMP)
```

What are you trying to accomplish with the DATEPART...GETDATE() business?

Comment: was just trying to pull total creatstamp count for each month. right now its just pulling data from May

Comment: Then the query above should work, as Dems pointed out, you were telling it to limit to just the last month by subtracting 1 month from the current month, but grouping by the YEAR and MONTH will give you a count for every year/month.